# Assigning address, data, and gas to smart contract to deploy with Node-js

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs, truffle-deployment

I used [this guide](https://gist.github.com/iisaint/0d46d71ea474d97ddc0e598ec998e76a) to deploy a smart contract with Node-js. I followed as far as my contract was created as an object. Because the mentioned guide is old some web3 methods changed nowadays. So it looks like i cannot continue following that. My question is "how do i assign address and data and gas to my contract object for deploying?". Please guide me with an appropriate code to deploy contract.

app.js:

```
var Web3=require('web3');
var fs=require('fs');
var solc=require('solc');
var web3=new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8545');
var address="0xdC3881248306fd62bbA5d9F0FDD39b5693bd1737";
var contractAbi=[
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "notation",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    }
];
var contract_sol=fs.readFileSync('E:/Deploy/contracts/Deploy.sol','utf8');
var contract_compiled=solc.compile(contract_sol);
for (let contractName in contract_compiled.contracts) {
var contract_byteCode=contract_compiled.contracts[contractName].bytecode;
}
var gasEstimate=web3.eth.estimateGas({data:contract_byteCode});
var contract_object=new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi);
```

Comment: what is `var address="0xdC3881248306fd62bbA5d9F0FDD39b5693bd1737";` for???

Comment: This is my Truffle address. I want to use it as address of contract creator.

Comment: Is your contract already deployed at that address?

Comment: No, i didn't deploy the contract.

Comment: So how are you planning to deploy it specifically at that address (why and how did you choose it)?

Comment: I can not understand what you mean. Can you explain more? Does it cause a problem?

Comment: You can't just choose which address the contract will be deployed at. Its (future) address depends on the account you're using for deployment (more precisely, this address is computed as a function of the account's address and nonce).

Comment: So how can i define an address for the contract?

Comment: You don't. You deploy it without specifying an address, and then you can get the address from the returned receipt.

Comment: Thanks. And about gas and bytecode what can i do?

Comment: I can give you a deployment script, but it assumes that you have already compiled the contract, and that its abi and bytecode are in files `<contractName>.abi` and `<contractName>.bin` respectively.

Comment: Contract is compiled with `var contract_compiled=solc.compile(contract_sol);`. For `.abi` i compiled that with Remix beforehand and `.abi` file achieved from there.

Comment: Do you want it or not?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: OK, so my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided in the question lacks just the followed command in the end of itself to a smart contract be deployed:

```
contract_object.deploy().send({from: address, gas: gasEstimate, gasPrice:1000000});
```

`address` is the address of deployer account and `gasEstimate` determines the required value of gas to deploy this contract. If you put the both in `.send(…)` just as

```
 send({from: address, gas: gasEstimate});
```

In fact, you are telling `contract_object` should be deployed  from the account with `address` address and with `gasEstimate` gas in the network.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the below code in the end of the question's code:

```
contract_object.deploy().send({from:<...>, gas:<...>, gasPrice:<...>});
```

I suggest you to read the below document to clear the syntax:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have already compiled the contract, and that its abi and bytecode are in files `<ContractName>.abi` and `<ContractName>.bin` respectively, you can use this script (web3 v1.2.1):

```
const fs   = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const NODE_ADDRESS  = "...";
const PRIVATE_KEY   = "...";
const CONTRACT_NAME = "...";
const CONTRACT_ARGS = [...];

async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, account, transaction) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
                gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3),
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function run() {
    const web3        = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
    const account     = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const abi         = fs.readFileSync(CONTRACT_NAME + ".abi", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const bin         = fs.readFileSync(CONTRACT_NAME + ".bin", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const contract    = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    const options     = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: CONTRACT_ARGS};
    const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
    const receipt     = await send(web3, account, transaction);
    console.log(receipt.contractAddress);
    if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. These two messages emerged and i don't know what should i do? 1- `The data field must be HEX encoded data.` and after that 2- `Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry:`. I don't know which transaction hash that means. Data field is `const options     = {data: "0x" + bin};`. I set `const NODE_ADDRESS  = "ws://127.0.0.1:8545";` and `const PRIVATE_KEY   =` to a private key belongs to a Ganache account.

Comment: Now that problem is eliminated. I set `const options = {data: "0x" + bin};` to the bytecode that exists in Truffle json file and the mentioned messages never emerge.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: It means that you don't have a proper byte code in the file `<CONTRACT_NAME >.bin`.

Comment: As I wrote at the top of the answer, it assumes that your bytecode is in file `<CONTRACT_NAME >.bin`. If you take it from the Truffle json output file, then I believe that it is already prefixed with `"0x"`. Run `console.log(bin)` and find out for sure.

Comment: Another problem. By this code the contract deployment occurs and Ganache shows it by a block mining. In the mined block it is mentioned that a smart contract created. But in contracts list of Ganache it is mentioned that the given contract is not deployed. What is the reason?

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: I don't know what `contracts list of Ganache` is. But say, I thought you were trying to deploy on some public network. If it's Truffle & Ganache that you'r working with, then why not simply use `const myContract = await artifacts.require('<MyContractName>').new(...)`???

Comment: I'm working on a private network and don't know nothing about an appropriate code to deploy a contract with Node-js.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: That's pretty much the opposite of answering my question: 1. The code in your IS the deployment of a contract with Node-js. 2. I asked why you are not using Truffle's built-in scheme for doing this.

Comment: 1- In fact i want whenever i click on a button on HTML the related smart contract be deployed in the private network. So i think here Node-js can help. 2- About Truffle built-in scheme i didn't know that and thank for your reminder about that.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: How could it be a reminder if you didn't know about it?

Comment: I used Truffle built-in scheme for deploying contract. I copy&pasted it in my app.js but an error says: `ReferenceError: artifatcs is not defined`.

Comment: Anyways i saw the code but didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: Truffle is designated for standalone testing, not to be integrated into a front-end application.

Comment: I can't understand your mean clearly. From HTML i can interact with a smart contract that deployed in a Truffle testnet. I can see its data and assign some data to it from HTML. But now, i need to deploy the contract from HTML event.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: Truffle is not a testnet, it's a client which interacts with a testnet (or even with the mainnet if you configure it properly).

Comment: So, how can i put a smart contract at a Truffle project such that the contract deployed with Node-js?

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: What do you mean "deployed with Node-js"? Truffle is a JS infrastructure, everything is executed in NodeJS.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean i didn't deploy that in Truffle console and with `truffle migrate` command.

Comment: I think Ganache doesn't consider that deployed contract from a truffle project. A block mined for that but in `Contracs` item in Ganache it is not deployed. Ganache just puts contracts belongs to a Truffle project there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are using truffle framework you can set your gas limit and gas price in your truffle-config.js file for different network and env like this:

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 7545,
    network_id: "*" // Match any network id
},
develop: {
  port: 8545
},
rinkeby: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
    network_id: 4,       // rinkeby's id
    gas: 6500000,        // rinkeby has a lower block limit than mainnet
    gasPrice: 10000000000
  }
}
};
```

Comment: I think you are using Rinkeby in your answer. But i want to use my own testnet. I think i should put `gas` and `gasPrice` in `development` field.